# Why is my canvas object hidden until mouseover?

Tags: jquery, canvas, paperjs

I'm using paper.js to create vector graphics on a canvas, but after drawing objects, they're only visible once I hover the mouse over the canvas.  Why?

Here's my code:

```
<canvas style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:999;" id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
paper.setup(canvas);
var rectangle = new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(50, 50), new paper.Point(150, 100));
var path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
```

And my jsFiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/enotech/qujEf/

Comment: If you add ```paper.view.draw()``` at the end does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either call: `paper.view.draw()` or `paper.view.update()` at end of your code to make it visible,
Updated Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qujEf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

In paper.js line 10545 that function is called when the mouse is moved into the view. That function calls handleMouseMove() which calls view.update() to update the canvas. I don't know paper.js, but it seems need to call this function yourself. So throw in a:

```
paper.view.update();
```

When you want to push your changes to the canvas.

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/qujEf/2/